# Runs as "debug" not "run" when I hit "run" icon

Tags: eclipse

anyone come across this behaviour before? know how to turn it off?

for some reason the last few hours, whenever I hit "run" to run the application it is like I had hit "debug". It runs in debug mode. But I am definitely pressing the run icon.

Comment: How do you know it's running on "debug"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Run button executes the last run configuration used. Click the down arrow on the button and choose the run configuration you want; that will become the new default.

Comment: seems I somehow fixed it... close eclipse and had to reboot computer because Eclipse wouldn't properly restart... something strange was going on...